# Flyway doesn't connect with PostgreSQL ft. Docker and Jenkins

Tags: postgresql, docker, jenkins, flyway

I've deployed Jenkins in Docker with help of this article (https://faun.pub/how-to-install-docker-in-jenkins-container-4c49ba40b373) because, it connects with host's docker sock allowing jenkins inside docker to manage docker in my host.

Now, I've deployed postgres as docker container and exposed 5432 to host. DB is initialised and working as expected.

In the pipeline, I'm running flyway as docker with conf and sql files, which means jenkins will try to run flyway as docker container in my host. No, matter what i give in 'flyway.url' it doesn't connect with DB.

**ERROR: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!**

**conf\flyway.conf**

```
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.29.2:5432/postgres
flyway.user=postgres
flyway.password=alpine98
flyway.connectRetries=60
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Temp'){
            steps {
                sh 'docker ps'
            }
        }
        stage('Version Check'){
            steps {
                sh 'docker run --rm flyway/flyway:9.15 version'
            }
        }
        stage('Migration') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker run --rm -v $WORKSPACE/db/migration:/flyway/sql -v $WORKSPACE/conf:/flyway/conf flyway/flyway:9.15 migrate'
            }
        }
        stage('Validation') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker run --rm -v $WORKSPACE/db/migration:/flyway/sql -v $WORKSPACE/conf:/flyway/conf flyway/flyway:9.15 validate'
            }
        }
        stage('Information') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker run --rm -v $WORKSPACE/db/migration:/flyway/sql -v $WORKSPACE/conf:/flyway/conf flyway/flyway:9.15 info'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**List of Docker Containers running in host:**

1. Jenkins - 172.17.0.2 - Exposed port 8080 and 50000
2. Postgres - 172.17.0.3 - Exposed port 5432
3. Flyway (will start when jenkins job runs)

*Since, all are deployed without network, all are mapped under default 'bridge' network*

**Jenkins Job Output**

```
+ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                                                                                                             NAMES
52365808825e   portainer/portainer-ce:latest   "/portainer"             13 hours ago   Up 13 hours   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, :::9000->9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9443->9443/tcp, :::9443->9443/tcp   portainer
ed6e91f86feb   gitea/gitea:1.18.5              "/usr/bin/entrypoint…"   13 hours ago   Up 13 hours   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:222->22/tcp, :::222->22/tcp                                                    gitea
fa32180a9a8c   postgres                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 hours ago   Up 13 hours   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp                                                                                         postgres
1f169b2b6f9c   jenkins/jenkins:lts             "/usr/bin/tini -- /u…"   13 hours ago   Up 12 hours   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp, :::50000->50000/tcp                                          jenkins
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Version Check)
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker run --rm flyway/flyway:9.15 version
Flyway Community Edition 9.15.2 by Redgate

Plugin Name           | Version | Licensed
--------------------- | ------- | --------
SqlFluffRulesEngine   | 1.2.1   | Licensed
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Migration)
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker run --rm -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ecp-flyway-integration_main/db/migration:/flyway/sql -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ecp-flyway-integration_main/conf:/flyway/conf flyway/flyway:9.15 migrate
ERROR: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Validation)
Stage "Validation" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Information)
Stage "Information" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please assist me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [default bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#use-the-default-bridge-network) "is considered a legacy detail of Docker and is not recommended for production use".  You should pretty much always `docker network create` a network and then `docker run --net` your containers on that network.

You will need to delete and recreate your database container.  But if you run it with

```bash
docker network create a_network
docker run -d \
  --net a_network \
  --name database \
  -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  postgres:15
```

then any container on the network `a_network` will be able to use the container name `database` as a host name.  You never need to know anything about the container-private IP addresses.

With this setup, you can use that host name in the Flyway configuration

```ini
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://database/postgres
```

and when you actually run the containers you need to put them on the network

```
sh 'docker run --net a_network --rm -v $WORKSPACE/db/migration:/flyway/sql -v $WORKSPACE/conf:/flyway/conf flyway/flyway:9.15 migrate'
```

This is a place where [Jenkins's Docker support](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) is lacking a little: while you almost always need a `--net` option, you need to provide it explicitly in the options list if you use that path to run a container.